# Set class fields by database columns

Tags: java

Good day,

I am trying to set class fields by database columns. for example

```
  Class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
   public int getId() {
    return id;
   }

   public void setsurname(int id) {
     this.surname = surname;
   }
   public int getsurname() {
    return surname;
   }

  }
```

and so on...

Then I select some field in Person class for example ;

```
"SELECT id FROM person"
```

Then I need to set id , it is easy but I don't know what I will set, I mean it could be surname, name or whatever. How do I set those fields. If I set this like;

```
person.setInt(rslt.getString("SURNAME"));
```

What if I didn't write SELECT surname from person. It will give error. How can I make these generic ?

Comment: Have you thought of looking at hibernate? It does EXACTLY what you're doing with annotations.

Comment: It sounds like JPA is what you are looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro.htm

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) for this. It provides direct mapping between your domain classes and the tables that inform them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commentators suggest, I'd use a JPA framework to do that, but if you prefer using raw JDBC, then you can use the method `ResultSet.getMetaData()` to obtain the number of columns and their names:

```
ResultSetMetaData md=rslt.getMetaData();
List<String> columns= new ArrayList<>();
for (var i=0;i<md.getColumnCount();i++) {
    columns.add(md.getColumnName(i+1)); //first one is in position 1, not 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of the JPA spec such as Hibernate is definitely what you are looking for. It is an ORM(Object Relational Mapper) that will allow you to map your domain to your database. It provides you with the ability to Insert, Update, Delete as well as Query your database based on the way you have mapped your Domain to your database. Here is a basic example:
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-annotations-1.html